# Children of dom-if not evaluated in test

Tags: polymer

When unittesting below example the paragraph is never shown. I have tests that check showContent for true which succeed but when I print out the element in the unittest, the template is closed immediately. I've tried wrapping the printing of the component in a flush but this doesn't help. Why is the dom-if not evaluated?

```
 <template is='dom-if' if='{{showContent}}'>
            <p>hello world</p>
        </template>
```

Comment: Can you provide the test code?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
    showContent:{
      type: Boolean,
      computed: '_computeshowContent(parameter)',
      value: null
    }
    _computeshowContent(parameter){
      if (parameter === 'something'){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I pass a true/false to showContent, so no need for a computed method

Answer (score 0):

There aren't enough code in your OP to give you a proper answer, but I guess you probably set the variable `showContent` wrong. You should use `this.set('showContent', true)` instead of `this.showContent = true`. The former sends an event to all elements that the variable has updated.